# matrix_world not giving correct results

Tags: python, transforms

I have a plane which I rotated up 90 degrees on *X* and 45 degrees on *Z*. I run this code to get the vertices world location's:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object
verts = [i.co * ob.matrix_world for i in ob.data.vertices]
print(verts)
```

The results I should get should be something like:

```
-0.707, -0.707, -1
0.707, 0.707, -1
-0.707, -0.707, 1
0.707, 0.707, 1
```

Instead I get:

```
-1.41, 7.1e-15, -1.19e-7
-1.19e-7, -1.06e-7, 1.41
1.19e-7, 1.06e-7, -1.41
1.41, -4.1e-15, 1.19e-7
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Is your plane at the origin (0,0,0)?

Comment: yes , it is @David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to multiply Matrix with Vector, order is important:

```
v2 = matrix * vector
```

see: [mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector)

Comment: that was it, thanks. I don't know why they don't make that a little more apparent though.

Comment: for a brief period in 2.5 series vector * matrix was valid, but it was changed to the algebraically more conventional matrix indexing, which made it m*v in 2.62 ( http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?240793-Changes-to-Matrices-for-Blender-2-62 )